# Code Igniter relationships

Tags: codeigniter

I'm starting to learn the PHP Code Igniter framework and I have a pretty basic question and I'm having problems finding some good sample code on the web.

Let's say I have 2 simple database tables (teacher and student).  Each has a unique identifier field (t_id and s_id).  Every student has a teacher so there is a s_t_id field in the student table which represents which teacher the student has.

I want to have a screen that lists all of the teachers with their students underneath.  Kind of like the teacher is a heading and the students belonging to that teacher are subheadings.

I think I could do this, but I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it or is it more of a hack?

I have a model for the teacher and the student and each has a controller.

But I load all of the data for both of them in the view for the teacher.  So my teacher controller code is something like this:

```
$data['teachers'] = $this->teachers_model->get_teachers();
$data['students'] = $this->students_model->get_students();
```

In my view, I just loop thru the teachers and get the students for each teacher in each iteration from the array passed to the view.

Does this seem like the proper way to do this following MVC patterns?  Or is this just a hack?  It seems kind of awkward to me to load the students in the controller for the teachers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the sparks package ( [php-activerecord](http://getsparks.org/packages/php-activerecord/versions/HEAD/show) )

It does a decent job of mapping relationships

**models/Teacher.php**  { *Model names = singular(teacher), DB Tables = plural(teachers)*  }

```
class Teacher extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    public static $has_many = array(array('Student'));

    //alternative is not to include where(conditions) clause

    public static function get_student_list($teacher_id){
         return (array) self::find(
                        'all', array(
                        'include'=>array('student'), //eager loading
                        'conditions'=>array('id=?', $teacher_id))
                         )->students;
    }
}
```

**models/Student.php**

```
class Student extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    public static $belongs_to = array(array('Teacher'));

}
```

**Teacher Controller**

```
class Teacher extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct(){parent::__construct();}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('teachers/_index', array(
          'students' => Teacher::get_student_list($this->teacher_id)
    ));
}
}
```

To make it work for you, have a read through the wiki [php-activerecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki)

Comment: but, as he states above, the screen shows *all* teachers with students listed underneath, so this would do a database query for *every* teacher, if there are 1000 teachers, that is 1000 queries is it not? (correct me if I am wrong!)

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'm not sure I understand what the array(array('Student')); is doing in both of the models?

Comment: e.g. would he not need to call (in view) `$teachers = Teacher::get_all(); foreach($teachers as $teacher) {$students = Teacher::get_student_list($teacher->t_id) /* now do echo stuff */}`

Comment: You could do something like..

$teacher = Teacher::all();  then foreach($teacher->student as $student), as long as mapping is setup correctly

Comment: @user103 array("Student") is being mapped, read the var names (belongs_to/has_many)

Comment: Maybe I'm getting in over my head.  But is there somewhere I can read about this (belongs_to/has_many) mapping stuff?  Id this a code ignitor thing or a php thing?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best practice if the database server do everything which is database-dependent.
If I understand you correctly, you want similar:

```
Teacher1
  Student1
  Student2
Teacher2
  ....
```

I think you need similar:

```
 SELECT teacher.name, GROUP_CONCAT(student.name) AS students
 FROM teacher
 JOIN student ON teacher.t_id=student.s_t_id
 GROUP BY teacher.t_id
```

Maybe this query isn't perfect but I think it results some rows, first column is teacher's name and the second column is his/her students separated by comma. If comma isn't good as separator you can change it, see [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

After this you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) so you'll have an array from specified teacher's students.

So you can solve your problem with one sql-query and some (equal with teachers count) php's explode function.

Answer (score 0):

Oky I would do like this if I were you,

Database

**Student Table**

```
id         : 1
name       : David
teacher_id : 2
```

**Teacher Table**

```
id          :1
name        : Sean

id          : 2
name        : Rose
```

**Your controller** // I am loading a view with name "view/index.php"

```
function index()
{
   $data['teachers'] = $this->teachers_model->get_teachers();
   $data['students'] = $this->students_model->get_students();
   $this->load->view('index',$data);
}
```

**Your view**

```
<?php

                foreach ($teacher as $t)
                {
                   echo 'Teacher Name:'.$t['name'];
                   echo '<br>';
                   foreach ($students as $s)
                   {
                       if($s['teacher_id]==$t['id'])
                       {
                            echo 'Student Name:'.$s['name'];
                            echo '<br>';
                       }
                   }
               }
    ?>
```